# app getting crash on click of tab in android

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am trying to create an app involving tabs, first tab works fine however on click of second tab the app crashes. I have looked up a lot on SO, and tried the suggestions, none is helping. Please look at the code and let me know the mistakes. Thanks in advance

Following is the main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            // Tab for data entry
            TabSpec data_entryspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Enter Data");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
            data_entryspec.setIndicator("Data Entry");
            Intent dataIntent = new Intent(this, DataEntry.class);
            data_entryspec.setContent(dataIntent);

            // Tab for statistics
            TabSpec check_resultspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("See Statistics");        
            check_resultspec.setIndicator("See Statistics");
            Intent statisticsIntent = new Intent(this, ShowResult.class);
            check_resultspec.setContent(statisticsIntent);


            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
            tabHost.addTab(data_entryspec); // Adding data tab
            tabHost.addTab(check_resultspec); // Adding statistics tab
    }

    }
```

the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Logcat:

```
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{colg.project.healthapp/colg.project.healthapp.ShowResult}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1797)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:540)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at colg.project.healthapp.ShowResult.onCreate(ShowResult.java:35)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-22 20:05:12.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     ... 18 more
```

Comment: The crash is happening in `ShowResult` not `MainActivity`, so you should post that code instead. The output is very clear. You have a `NullPointerException` in the `onCreate()` of `ShowResult`. So you are trying to do work on an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: yaaa....thanx...corrected the error...thanks for pointing it out...